# How to add special service for passenger?

Tags: sabre

I using SpecialServiceLLSRQ to add special service for passenger, but the response Sabre return errors, i dont understand what mean's of response ?
This is my request:

```
<SpecialServiceRQ Version="2.3.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:ns2="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" ReturnHostCommand="true">
        <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <Service SSR_Code="SPML" SegmentNumber="1">
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" />
                <Text>TEST</Text>
            </Service>
        </SpecialServiceInfo>
    </SpecialServiceRQ>
```

This is the response:

```
<SpecialServiceRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
        <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2019-03-06T04:06:21-06:00">
                <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                    <stl:HostCommand LNIATA="623814">3SPML1/TEST-1.1</stl:HostCommand>
                    <stl:Message>.USE 4 ENTRY.NOT ENT BGNG WITH</stl:Message>
                    <stl:Message>3SPML1/TEST-1.1</stl:Message>
                    <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
                </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            </stl:Error>
        </stl:ApplicationResults>
    </SpecialServiceRS>
```

How can i fix this issue? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Just to contextualize, SPML it is the acronym for Special Meals. try to use a code to specify what kind of food you would like. Ex.: VGML - Vegetarian Lacto-ovo Meal

Note: for VVML - Vegetarian Vegan Meal (some airlines require VGML). You have to consider this kind of limitation.

To add a SSR you have to Retrieve the reservation (TravelItineraryReadRQ), add the SSR (PassengerDetailsRQ) and Save the information(PassengerDetailsRQ)

> I'm abstracting the factor of open/close sessions, I'm presume you have a valid token
>   properly inserted into header for each request.

To retrieve the reservation (TravelItineraryReadRQ):

```
  <v3:TravelItineraryReadRQ TimeStamp="${P-S#Timestamp}" Version="3.8.0">
     <v3:MessagingDetails>
        <v3:SubjectAreas>
           <v3:SubjectArea>FULL</v3:SubjectArea>
        </v3:SubjectAreas>
     </v3:MessagingDetails>
     <v3:UniqueID ID="YOUR PNR CODE"/>
  </v3:TravelItineraryReadRQ>
```

To add SSR - (PassengerDetailsRQ):

```
  <v3:PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.3.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="false">
     <v3:SpecialReqDetails>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <v3:SpecialServiceRQ>
           <v3:SpecialServiceInfo>
              <!--Mandatory-->
              <!--Repeat Factor=1-99-->
              <v3:Service SegmentNumber="1" SSR_Code="VGML">
                 <v3:PersonName NameNumber="1.1"/>
                 <v3:VendorPrefs>
                    <v3:Airline Hosted="true"/>
                 </v3:VendorPrefs>
              </v3:Service>
           </v3:SpecialServiceInfo>
        </v3:SpecialServiceRQ>
     </v3:SpecialReqDetails>
  </v3:PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

To save the information added (ER) - (PassengerDetailsRQ):

```
  <v3:PassengerDetailsRQ version="3.3.0" HaltOnError="true" IgnoreOnError="false">
     <v3:PostProcessing IgnoreAfter="false" RedisplayReservation="true">
        <v3:EndTransactionRQ>
           <v3:EndTransaction Ind="true">
              <v3:Email Ind="true"/>
           </v3:EndTransaction>
           <v3:Source ReceivedFrom="APPNAME/USERNAME"/>
        </v3:EndTransactionRQ>
     </v3:PostProcessing>
  </v3:PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

xmlns:v3="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3"

IATA meal [codes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Air_Transport_Association_code)

- ALML - Allergen Meal
- AVML - Asian Vegetarian Meal
- BBML - Baby Meal
- CAKE - Birthday Cake (on SAS)
- BLML - Bland Meal
- CHML - Children Meal
- CLML - Celebration Cake Meal
- DBML - Diabetic Meal
- FPML - Fruit Platter Meal
- GFML - Gluten Intolerant Meal
- HFML - High Fibre Meal
- HNML - Hindu Non-Vegetarian Meal
- OBML - Japanese Obento Meal (on United Airlines)
- JPML - Japanese Meal (on Japan Airlines)
- JNML - Junior Meal
- KSML - Kosher Meal
- KSMLS - Kosher Meal (Snack)
- LCML - Low Calorie Meal
- LFML - Low Fat Meal
- NBML - No Beef Meal (on China Airlines)
- NFML - No Fish Meal (on Lufthansa)
- NLML - No Lactose Meal
- LPML - Low Protein Meal
- PRML - Low Purin Meal
- LSML - Low Salt Meal
- MOML - Muslim Meal
- ORML - Oriental Meal
- PFML - Peanut Free Meal
- RFML - Refugee Meal (on United Airlines)
- SFML - Seafood Meal
- SPML - Special Meal, Specify Food
- VJML - Vegetarian Jain Meal
- VLML - Vegetarian Lacto-ovo Meal
- VOML - Vegetarian Oriental Meal
- RVML - Vegetarian Raw Meal
- VVML - Vegetarian Vegan Meal (some airlines require VGML)

Important note: When you add text to further define a generic SSR code such as OTHS, or SPML, use plain text. You can use a space between the words. Avoid special characters because the system returns the error message: INVALID FREE TEXT CHARACTERS. MODIFY AND RE-ENTER.NOT ENT BGNG WITH

Comment: If the error says "USE 4", he may also be dealing with AA flights

Comment: I think it does not matter, because he does use sabre webservices, actually he should uses this transactions(mentioned above), I mean the most generic ones to cover the most airlines. For example specifying what kind of special meal, some airlines like Latam, American Airlines, Lufthansa and etc.. requiere a different approach, I mean different meal codes. In case of Sabrecommand he has to use the correct input (in the end of the day the WS will mimics the Sabre commands, but as good practice we should avoid to use Sabrecommand in API's implementations

Comment: When you receive a USE 4 ENTRY it is indicating that `//Service/VendorPrefs/Airline/@Hosted = true` should have been used. This flag needs to be set to true when segments on the PNR are with AA, all other airlines would have Hosted=false (or not set).